# i want to make a program that take number from user and check whether that number is in sequence or not

Tags: c

[image]

Each time when i enter a number it does not check with the previous one !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: `prev = num` should be *before* you read the new number.

Comment: `if (first >0 && first == 1)` why not just `if (first == 1)`?

Comment: I cannot read the screen shot. Please post text as text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting `prev = num` too early so you are losing the old value of `prev`, which is what you need to compare against. it looks like you've then hacked around that problem by arbitrarily decreasing prev by one, but then of course it looks to the program like you are always in sequence, which is a nonsensical solution.

You need to fix the actual problem, not try to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the `num` variable when you declare it, so when you set `prev=num`, prev is going to be a random number (positive or negative) and, if it's greater than your input the first check (`prev<num`) will be wrong.